# Angular-chart.js - How to animate a chart per click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I have two Charts (created with Angular Chart JS). I want to reload the animation per mouse click - So for this i created a button for each chart and added a function.

At the moment all charts will be reloaded, when I click to one of the button. But I want that only the chart will be reloaded, which belongs to the button (So Button1 should reload Chart1, Button2 reload Chart2 etc.)

How can i solve that ? Here is my Code and the link to my plunker:

HTML File:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="jsonServerBox">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules" ng-style="{'background-color': module.background, 'color': module.fontcolor, 'border': module.border}">
  <input type="button" ng-click="render()" value="render"/>
  <div class=""><canvas id="base" class="chart chart-base" widht="" chart-type="module.type" chart-data="module.data" chart-labels="module.labels" chart-series="module.series" chart-colours="module.colors" chart-options="module.options"></canvas></div>              
</li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

App JS:

```
 var charts = [];
 $scope.$on('create', function (event, chart) {
  charts.push(chart);
 });
$scope.render = function () {
  charts.forEach( function (chart) {
    chart.render();
  });
};
```

Link to Punker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/N8xJziIXepIZYweoJpaq?p=preview